# How to average FFT(vector) values in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, visual-c++, average

I have vectors that shows calculated FFT values. I also try to calculate average values of FFT but face with some container errors. How can I calculate average of the vectors for seconds/blocks?

Here is my code;

```
int numberOfSamples = 0;
int numberOfBlocks = 10;
std::vector<double> fftSpectrum;
VectorOutputChannel fftOut;
VectorOutputChannel fftAverage;

    void DemonProcessorModule::calculateFft(const std::vector<Sample>& inputSignal)
    {
        for (const auto& sample : inputSignal)
        {
            fft.timeDomain[numberOfSamples] = window[numberOfSamples] * sample.value;
            ++numberOfSamples;
    
            if (numberOfSamples == m_fftLength)
            {
                numberOfSamples = 0;
                fft.calculate();
    
                for (size_t i = 0; i < fftSpectrum.size(); ++i)
                {
                    fftSpectrum[i] = std::abs(fft.frequencyDomain[i]);
                }
    
                fftOut.addVector(fftSpectrum);
            }
        }
    }
  void FFT::calculate()
  {
   ....
   float average = accumulate(fftSpectrum.begin(), fftSpectrum.end(), 0.0 / 
   fftSpectrum.size());
   fftAverage.addVector(average);
  }
```

Comment: what errors do you get? Please post a [mcve] and the compiler error message. Btw You want `0.0)  / fftSpectrum.size();` rather than `0.0 / fftSpectrum.size());`

Comment: besides that your call to `accumulate` looks ok, its not clear what the issue is

Comment: Even though the values are small, it might be better if you worked entirely in double instead of mixing double and float.  You are probably using a machine with lots of memory: no need to worry about sizes

Comment: Actually, when I Debug this code it works without error when I select input channel in interface it gives an error "tMAthExContainer.DoCalc" as source and gives a message "External exception E06D7363"

Comment: Well, the code shown doesn't mention `tMAthExContainer` nor `DoCalc`. The issue lies somewhere in the code not shown. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve].